# How to structure condition with StringLike OR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My goal is to allow read access to some resources and modify access to some resources based on the tag of those resources. I want the modify access to include the read access. For example the "ReadBy" and "ModifyBy" tags.

Here is simplified version of what I came up with:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ScopedReadPermissionsForReadUsers",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ssm:GetParameter*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:ResourceTag/ReadBy": [
            "*${aws:userid}*"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ScopedReadPermissionsForModifyUsers",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ssm:GetParameter*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:ResourceTag/ModifyBy": [
            "*${aws:userid}*"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ScopedModifyPermissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ssm:PutParameter",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:ResourceTag/ModifyBy": [
            "*${aws:userid}*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above code works as expected. However, I would like to avoid having to duplicate the `ssm:GetParameters*` permission because in reality it will be a longer action list and permissions may get out of sync. Ideally I would OR together the entries under the StringLike, similar to the following, but I understand this does not work how I feel it should (as indicated in the diagram).

```
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:ResourceTag/ReadBy": [
            "*${aws:userid}*"
          ],
          "aws:ResourceTag/ModifyBy": [
            "*${aws:userid}*"
          ]
        }
      }
```

[image: AWS Condition Diagram from Docs]
[Source: IAM JSON policy elements: Condition operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html#reference_policies_multiple-conditions-eval)

Again the goal is to allow read-only access via the `ReadBy` tag and then have the `ModifyBy` tag be the exact permissions from the `ReadBy` tag plus additional modify permissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want OR you have to have separate statements as you have now. You can maybe only try to combine the two `ModifyBy` stetments.

Comment: Yes, I plan on keeping the `ModifyBy` read permissions separate from the write permissions to allow for quick copy/paste from the `ReadyBy` permissions. In reality this is all managed via CloudFormation, which unfortunately provides no native functions to help with this.